# Bash Cutting a Filename as a String in a Find Loop?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use the `cut` function to parse filenames, but am encountering difficulty while doing so in a find loop With the intention of converting my music library from `ARTIST - TITLE.EXT` to `TITLE.EXT`

So If I had the file `X - Y.EXT` it should yield `Y.EXT` as an output.

The current function is something like this:

```
find . -iname "*.mp3" -exec cut -d "-" -f 2 <<< "`echo {}`" \;
```

It should be noted that the above syntax looks a bit strange, why not just use `<<< {} \;` instead of the `echo {}`. cut seems to parse the file instead of the filename if it's not given a string.

Another attempt I had looked something like:

```
find . -iname "*.mp3" -exec TRACKTITLE=`echo {} | cut -d '-' -f2` \; -exec echo "$TRACKTITLE" \;
```

But this fails with `find: ‘TRACKTITLE=./DAN TERMINUS - Underwater Cities.mp3’: No such file or directory`.

This (`cut -d "-" -f 2 <<< FILENAME`) command works wonderfully for a single instance (although keeps the space after the "-" character frustratingly).

How can I perform this operation in a find loop?

Comment: You're using shell syntax, but `-exec` doesn't start a shell unless it's told to (as by exec'ing something like `/bin/sh`). Consequently, that syntax gets run by the calling shell _before_ find is started, not once per item it finds.

Comment: Consider also alternatives that don't require `-exec` at all; `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do ...; done`, f/e. [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) covers a wide variety of approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is try to extract what you want in your file name with [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073).

```
file="ARTIST - TITLE.EXT"

echo "${file#* - }"
```

Output

```
TITLE.EXT
```

---

Using find and invoking a shell with a for loop.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec sh -c 'for music; do echo mv -v "$music" "${music#* - }"; done' sh {} +
```

---

If there are *.mp3* files in sub directories, just change

```
-exec
```

with

```
-execdir
```

if available/supported by your `find`

---

For whatever reason `-execdir` is not available.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec sh -c '
  for music; do
    pathname="${music%/*}"
    filename="${music##*/}"
    new_music="${filename#* - }"
    echo mv -v "$music" "$pathname/$new_music"
  done' sh {} +
```

- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.
- See [Understanding -exec option to Find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Comment: The `"${music#* - }"` will also cut the directory portion, if the file found is in a subdirectory. `find` is superflous if all files are in the top directory (It is still superflous even if they are not).

Comment: @M.NejatAydin, yes and `-execdir` should fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Below command would say what it would do, remove `echo` to actually
run mv:

```
find . -iname "*.mp3" -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | cut -d - -f2)"' sh {} \;
```

Example output:

```
$ find . -iname "*.mp3" -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | cut -d - -f2)"' sh {} \;
mv ./X - Y.mp3  Y.mp3
mv ./ARTIST - TITLE.mp3  TITLE.mp3
```

Also notice that your `cut` command will leave a whitespace at the
beginning of the new filename:

```
$ echo ARTIST\ -\ TITLE.mp3 | cut -d - -f2-
 TITLE.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `find` nor the `cut` for this task.

```
for f in *' - '*.mp3; do mv -i "$f" "${f##* - }"; done
```

will do the job for the current directory.

If you want to descend through directories, then:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*' - '*.mp3; do
    mv -i "$f" "${f%/*}/${f##* - }"
done
```